# Download a file from google drive

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

First of all, sorry for my english. Second, I want to make an app that, at every launch download a .txt file from google drive, the file is defined (I mean, it's in drive). It's just a single file, but, when I launch the app, the file is downloaded, but dosen't contain anything.. 
Here is my code:

```
Private Function ReadLine(ByVal Line As Integer, ByVal lista As List(Of String)) As String
    Return lista(Line - 1)
End Function
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable() = True Then
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://doc-14-7c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/17t22h2a63tpkhdgv047v6i0s5a9o8bm/qgqjocmi87jt0up72gfpg9dseeo3pt84/1458396000000/07699472972018131827/07699472972018131827/0B8iVIf__yN1FUDV1STNWODJUYms?e=download&nonce=5jnki0mtgo520&user=07699472972018131827&hash=0gi5r6k7rm2uob14062tlbsk0nhpkoo1", _
                                         "C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier)
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier)
        Dim lista As New List(Of String)
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            lista.Add(reader.ReadLine)
        End While
        reader.Close()
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fisier2) = False Then
            lblWould.Text = ReadLine(1, lista)
        Else
            Dim nr As Integer
            nr = Val(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(fisier2))
            nrx = nr
        End If
        Dim contain As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier)
        contain = contain.Replace(lblWould.Text, "SEEN!")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier, contain, False)
    Else
        MsgBox("Trebuie sa fi connectat la internet!")
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnYes.Click, btnNo.Click
    Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier)
    Dim lista As New List(Of String)
    Dim a As String
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        a = reader.ReadLine()
        If Not a = "SEEN!" Then
            lista.Add(reader.ReadLine)
        End If
    End While
    lblWould.Text = lista(nrx + 1)
    nrx += 1
    Dim contain As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier)
    contain = contain.Replace(lblWould.Text, "SEEN!")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\WINDOWS\" & fisier, contain, False)
End Sub`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well going to your link in a normal web browser shows an empty page, so your link clearly seems to be incorrect (or one must authenticate oneself). And as I see it appears to refer to the Google Documents, you probably cannot download it and expect it to be a plain text file either. For that you would need it to be a plain text file in the beginning.

Comment: In firefox, it downloads a file..

Comment: Well are you logged in to Google Drive in Firefox? Because I get nothing, and nor will your application if you're required to be logged in.

Comment: Also, while debugging aplications, you should never have empty At least add a `Messagebox,Show(e.ToString)` that pops up a window if you have an error.

Comment: This is what i get..: http://www.girlshare.ro/3489306763.8

Comment: Hmm meant to say "empty try.. Catch"

Comment: Wow, I ain't downloading anything from that site. Still, it doesn't matter what you get in your browser if your application doesn't get anything at all. You'll need a direct link to the file that is accessible at any time.

Comment: @VisualVincent , but i need to edit that file, it's a program that shows some things, from that file, i used google drive, 'cuse, there i can edit my file whithout even changing it's download link..

Comment: Well you cannot edit it via your application, if the application is not downloading it, right? I got a 403 response in my web browser, so in order for you to download the file _from the link in your code_, your application must be logged in (which is not the easiest). You need a more direct link that is open to everyone.

Comment: @VisualVincent , ok, But, how colud i edit the file? Beacuse, i need edit every day...

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Google Drive that much. Though we still don't know if GD is capable of a direct link.